LIsten on a port, check another port, if no response run a script, then tunnel connection to that port?
So, I want to use an SSH tunnel proxy occasionally. But I don't want to fire it up manually every time. And this is a laptop so if I just start the SSH tunnel at startup it might die of an occasional network change or sleep.
I guess I could use autossh to keep it alive. But ideally I would rather just have it fire up automatically when I try to access it.
I was thinking of the good old autofs principle of "mounting oт attempted access". So, have something listen on port A, check if port B is responding (it's all localhost so I don't need long timeouts), if port B is not responding, run a script. When port B is responding, just transparently tunnel the connection from fort A to port B.
However, I a not very experienced at writing socket code, and on top of that I'd probably have to do it in C, as my usual scripting tool, Python, might overuse CPU if tunneling a high speed connection chunk by chunk (watching a video/downloading a big file over the proxy).
Is there any ready tool for this kind of thing, or failing that a ready code sample?
(I mean, it would be even better if a tool could monitor specifically for refused connections on the proxy port, without having to tunnel one port to another after starting the SSH process)

What you're looking for is called "Port Knocking", and there are tools. E.g. https://github.com/mrash/fwknop See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortKnocking

Sounds great, except it's implemented on the firewall and the firewall does not listen to the loopback interface?
